# Vue method download attribute not working it redirecting to url

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods

```js
var fileURL = this.fileBasePath+file;
var fileLink = document.createElement('a');
fileLink.href = fileURL;
fileLink.setAttribute('download',file);
document.body.appendChild(fileLink);
fileLink.click();
```

Actually, I want to instant download
Please help me to solve this problem , thanks advance

Comment: It would be best to show the whole method and template

Comment: in the template, I have  only  a button, after clicking some verification and then I want to download some file @Dan

Comment: I don't think any better way is available. libraries uses the same way with more robust code but **same way**